# Get Matterport Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

We are developing a matterport 3d virtual tour iframe to show within our websites and would like to know the solution for returning the url for the thumbnail image without having to enter the iframe.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. What code have you tried? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: I need the answer to this too. If you find out, please update this question

Answer (score 5):

I found this link in the Editor. Look through the right hand column and expand the Showcase Sharing section in the right hand column. There should be an entry for Thumbnail image, which will look something like
https://my.matterport.com/api/v1/player/models/mmmmmmmmmmm/thumb

where the m's are the ID of the property used in the m= URL parameter.

I think you probably need to set the thumbnail in the editor as well (I've been working on the front end not the editing)

Comment: Do you know whether it's also possible to get gallery images in a similar way?